# How to solve the event race condition in angular js composite controller

Tags: angularjs, events

Lets say I have 2 controllers, a main one that controls the entire page, and a sub controller for a specific region in the page.

when sub controller loads it registers to an event that the main controller fires when it's ready with data.

How can I assure the event is not fired before the sub controller registered ?

Comment: You have to fire main controller event when sub controller event fired?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Where is the data coming from ? If it's a matter of using the data in both controller you should consider using a service to share it instead of firing events.